# Agrupar y Sumar Cantidades de Materiales por Nombre

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo un sistema donde almacenamos nombres de materiales que están ligados a un numero único. Esto es por que cada numero único es un numero de parte y lleva sus respectivos materiales para producirlo, lo que busco hacer es un resumen de materiales que llevaría en general. Por el momento enlisto numero de parte por numero de parte describiendo los materiales que cada uno lleva, pero en lugar de ello, busco que me agrupe todos los materiales que se llamen igual y se sumen sus cantidades respectivas.

Actualmente el sistema lo tengo asi:
Como se puede ver cada Numero Unico (Lista de la derecha) contiene una pequeña lista de materiales, los cuales se repiten en cada plano, busco hacer una lista general, donde solo se muestren todos los materiales que se llamen igual y sumar las cantidades que hay en cada numero unico.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que tengo para generar la lista de Materiales:

```
<?php 
$sql1 = $db->query("SELECT planos_de_ot.*, lista_planos.id AS nuevoid FROM planos_de_ot INNER JOIN lista_planos ON lista_planos.num_unico = planos_de_ot.plano WHERE planos_de_ot.id_ot = ".$id." ORDER BY id");
?>
<h3>Materiales:</h3>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <?php foreach($sql1 as $lista):
            $sql2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM materiales_planos WHERE id_plano = ".$lista['nuevoid']."");
            ?>
        <li class="list-group-item"><h4><strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i> - <?php echo $lista['plano']?></strong></h4>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th class="text-center">Nombre Material</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Cantidad</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($sql2 as $nuevainfo):?>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $nuevainfo['nombre_material']?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $nuevainfo['cantidad']?></td>
                </tbody>
                <?endforeach;?>
            </table>
        </li>
        <?endforeach;?>
    </ul>
```

Estas son las tablas de mi base de datos:
**-Tabla Ordenes Trabajo**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**-Tabla donde guardo los Numeros Unicos que se utilizaran para la Orden de trabajo**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**-Tabla donde guardo los materiales de cada plano**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcos Saúl Cañas Vázquez,
¿Si no me he equivocado, lo que deseas seria eso ?

**1- Agrupa y sumar las cantidades por  nombre.**

```
SELECT 
NOMBRE_MATERIAL,SUM(CANTIDAD)AS CANTIDAD
FROM MATERIALES_PLANOS
GROUP BY NOMBRE_MATERIAL
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2- Agrupar y sumar todos materials que se llamen igual por numero unico**
  Debes crear index en la columna id de la tabla planos_de_ot
  Debes crear index en la columns id_plano de la tabla materiales_planos

En la imagene a la derecha no hay itens en duplicidad
  Hizo un prueba con algunos.

La consulta de ser de esa forma

```
   SELECT 
   PO.PLANO,MT.NOMBRE_MATERIAL,SUM(MT.CANTIDAD)AS CANTIDAD
   FROM MATERIALES_PLANOS MT
   INNER JOIN PLANOS_DE_OT PO ON MT.ID_PLANO = PO.ID
   GROUP BY PO.PLANO,MT.NOMBRE_MATERIAL
```

**3 - Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**4 - Imagene final**

Se no hay index en las tablas, puedes crearlos para mejorar el resultado.
   create index ix_idplan on materiales_planos(id_plano)
   create index ix_id on planos_de_ot(id)

La consulta es la misma que encuentrase en el item 2.
   Es solo agregar la consulta en código.

[image: Resultado Final]

***Atención: Siempre haga una cópia de seguridad de tus códigos.***

Comment: Básicamente ese es el resultado que deseo, el problema es que en la BD tengo la informacion guardada en tablas separadas, donde primero tengo que consultar cuales numeros unicos son los que necesito, posteriormente consultar cuales materiales son para cada numero unico.

Comment: Por favor pone ejemplos de las tablas que tienes para vea se puedo ayudarte de otra forma. Entonces hay mas tablas e solo las dos que has añadido.

Comment: Marcos Saúl, hizo una actualización. Mira el iten 2 y tres.

Comment: He añadido una imagene final de tudo que tu necesitas.
Las tablas que tienes son suficientes para el resultado deseado.
Mira el PLANO F-7528 donde he duplicado los nombres con cantidads diferentes. La suma de las dos es la agrupación que necesitas.

Comment: Que tal Bonfim, lamento la demora estuve ocupado con otras cosas de mi proyecto que al final olvide entrar al sitio, he estado utilizando las consultas que me estas brindando, pero no me dan el resultado esperado, ya que por ejemplo el material llamado PHILIPS #6 X 1/2 DE ACERO esta duplicado por estar en planos diferentes, mientras que lo esperado es que todos los materiales que llamen por igual se agrupen y se sumen sus cantidades (Claro, dependiendo de los Numeros Unicos que esten ligados a un Proyecto o Orden de Trabajo)

Comment: Marcos, creo que no lo he comprendido.Contestame por favor: 1-¿Quienes son(que se llamen por igual)?. 2-Indique en la tabla los numeros unicos. 3-El material PHILIPS se ha duplicado pero pertenence a un, mismo id_plano.
Se estoy cierto; PHILIPS está vinculado al id_plano 11 que pertenece al id 11 tabla planos_de_ot(F-7528).
Se así es não duplicidad. Los materiales deberian tener un codigo para que la agrupación sea por codigo e no por nombre.